# HERE Maps Traffic API directions

Tags: here-api

I'm new to Here Maps Traffic API and i'm trying to find out how to know which direction is the QD(+ or -) pertaining to. Is it north or south? Thank you for answering my question.

Answer (score 0):

From: **[Traffic API Guide - Common Acronyms](https://developer.here.com/documentation/traffic/topics/common-acronyms.html)**

> ***QD***
>
> *This data type indicates the Queuing Direction (QD) of the traffic. When traffic becomes congested, a queue of vehicles begins to build up in the opposite direction to the driving direction. The value can be "+" or "-". The value "-" indicates that the traffic is queued in the opposited direction to the driving direction.*